# afterCellEdit for subGrid ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Do we have any api in ui-grid to capture the cell edit event for sub grid(expanded grid)?

Just like gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit which works for parent grid?

Thanks in advance!